# asp.net MVC3 + Visual Web Developer 2010 Express + global.asax + cannot load type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

I have tried to google this problem and followed many suggestions, such as replacing dll's, re-installing MVC3, and more. Therefore I do try to approach this really great forum, even tough this question has been around here and there. But I think this error is general and I guess can be caused by many reasons.

The Problem:
I have made with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express an asp.net MVC3 web application with 'Internet' template. After many tries, this time I called it 'MvcAnotherTest'. It runs OK on my local machine. 
I Re-built the solution and copied these files to my domain root on Windows Web Host account server:

```
MvcAnotherTest.dll
Global.asax
Global.asax.cs (don't think that it needed but tried with it and without it).
Web.config
System.Web.Routing
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Abstractions
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.WebPages
```

And also:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

But no matter what I do, I get this error below when I try browsing to the site:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MvcAnotherTest.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcAnotherTest.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

I configured the iis to 7 and the asp.net runtime to 4/4.5

Comment: When you say you "copied these files", what exactly did you do?  You should use the Visual Studio Publishing wizard to publish the files, either to GoDaddy directly via the ftp deployment or publish to a local directory, then copy all of those files to GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem...did you solve it?

I had to remove the Global.asax.cs file completely in order for it to function.